# What bit stand for in sql?

Tags: sql

when i take a data type as bit and when i insert 0 or 1  in that columns of the table then it give error. so please tell me how to remove the error?

Comment: You need to tell us **WHAT** database you're using! And: **what** error are you getting?? What does the error message say??

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing a lot of required details.

If this is Microsoft SQL Server and you are entering them through the Table Editor in SSMS you need to type "True"  or "False"

Answer (score 0):

Bit means boolean, as the other two responders have said.

However, boolean values can be displayed in various ways. 1 and 0, true and false, 'Yes' and 'No' are examples. Try each of these, and if you're still not getting anywhere, let us know!

Good luck.